# Android studio 1.0.2 icon setup

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android studio IDE. I have downloaded the latest version 1.0.2 and i can't find an option to customize app icon when i'm initially creating project. Previously i have used eclipse. let me know if there is a option and also if anyone has the tutorial on how to get started with android studio, provide me the links.

Answer (score 1):

- Open `Search EveryWhere` by Double Shift at Android Studio
- Type `image asset` + Enter

You'll see wizard for that

[image]

Comment: Thanks:) and also if you have any tutorial on studio pls provide me the link.

Comment: [Android Studio Overview](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html), you can start from there, also see *Help* menu at AS